# How to get attachments Url in all folder use javascript

Tags: infopath, jquery, caml-query, url, attachments

[image: folders]

I want to retrieve file Url in all of that folder. I use javascript. Problem is it console the last item. I do not know why. Please help. Thanks

[image: This is code]

```
function checkAttachment(AttachID,getAttachmentStatus){
var itemId = AttachID;
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
for(var i = 0; i<itemId.length; i++){
  if(getAttachmentStatus[i] == true){
        var attachmentFolder=web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Lists/Purchase2/Attachments/'+itemId[i]);
        //console.log(attachmentFolder);
        attachmentFiles = attachmentFolder.get_files();
        console.log(attachmentFiles);
        ctx.load(attachmentFiles);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onGetAttachmentSucc),Function.createDelegate(this,this.onGetAttachmentFail));
        }           
  }
}
function onGetAttachmentSucc(sender, args) {    
console.log(attachmentFiles);                              
var i=0;
  for(var file in attachmentFiles)
  {   
        if(attachmentFiles.itemAt(i) != undefined){             
            console.log(attachmentFiles.itemAt(i).get_serverRelativeUrl());
            i++;
        }

  }
}

function onGetAttachmentFail(sender, args) {
 alert("sorry!");}
```

sorry for my dirty code T_T

Comment: Why are you making a loop with itemId.length? Is it an array? Could you insert the code here instead of the image?

Comment: because the folder is a different path. From the first picture when I attach a file in a form it will create a new folder and add the file to it. it checks by Id. I want to get all file URL from all folder. Do you understand? Sorry for my weak English skill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the variable AttachID is an array of item ids, you can do like this (using the REST api):

```
function checkAttachment(AttachID, getAttachmentStatus) {
    var itemId = AttachID;
    for (var i = 0; i < itemId.length; i++) {
        if (getAttachmentStatus[i] == true) {

            var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Lists/Purchase2/Attachments/" + itemId[i] + "')/Files?$select=ServerRelativeUrl";

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose' },
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    var attachments = data.d.results;
                    if (attachments) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < attachments.length; j++) {
                            console.log(attachments[j].ServerRelativeUrl);
                        }
                    }

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("sorry!");
                }
            })

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got undefined when I use _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl I use sharepoint 2010